# R: How to check if multiple columns' values exist in a list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with columns containing words that make up an ngram. I would like to sum up the number of stopwords in each ngram and add this column to the dataframe but I can't think of an elegant way to do it with multiple values for n (4-grams, 5-grams etc. . .).

**So far I have been doing the following**:

```
mutate(Bigram_Counts_By_Company,
   stopword_count = (word1  %in% stop_words$word) %>% as.integer() +
                    (word2 %in% stop_words$word) %>% as.integer())
```

Now this works but I'd so much rather write a general function that does the same with all columns starting with "name".

**What I'd like to do**:

```
mutate(Web_Bigram_Counts_By_Company,
   stopword_count = select(Web_Bigram_Counts_By_Company, starts_with("word")) %in% stop_words$word)
```

`select(Web_Bigram_Counts_By_Company, starts_with("word"))` works great to select the columns whose names start with 'name', but when I use it in the call to mutate I get this error: `Column 'stopword_count' must be length 360463 (the number of rows) or one, not 2`

Is this just a simple R fundamentals error or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Try with `mutate_at`i.e. `Web_Bigram_Counts_By_Company %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("name")), funs(yourfunction))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried this, and was given the following error : `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column 'word1' is of unsupported type NULL`. I love the idea though, I might just be going about it wrong, but I'm sure the column is of type 'char'

Comment: Please check the `str` of the data if it is a `list` column or not